# How to get sheet name in the spreadsheet from other sheet when i have edit permission

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use the IMPORTRANGE function to get data from other sheets, and there are many sheet names so it takes a lot of time to copy the sheet name into the IMPORTRANGE list. Is there any way I can get all the names of a sheet completely automatically?
I want:  input("google sheet URL") and Output("List sheet name")
Or has  attribute of IMPORTRANGE that get data of all sheets in spreadsheet

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Start by reading https://deevelopers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. If you need further help, please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: What information is on your list to start with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Get Sheetnames for a Spreadsheet

```
function getSheetNames(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  Logger.log( ss.getSheets().map(sh => sh.getName()).join('\n'));
}
```